# No support for the type of the given DataStream: GenericType<org.apache.flink.types.Row> Flink Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink

I want to write a stream of rows to Cassandra.
First, I convert the Avro stream to a row stream. There are no errors shown while compiling.
See the code below: (Both KafkaConsumer and CassandraSink work fine separately in other jobs)

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment environment =  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// Initialize KafkaConsumer
FlinkKafkaConsumer010 kafkaConsumer = KafkaConnection.getKafkaConsumer(AvroSchemaClass.class, inTopic, schemaRegistryUrl, properties);

// Set KafkaConsumer as source
DataStream<AvroSchemaClass> avroInputStream = environment.addSource(kafkaConsumer);

// converting avro message to flink's row datatype.
// see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/formats/avro/AvroRowDeserializationSchema.html
AvroRowDeserializationSchema avroToRow = new AvroRowDeserializationSchema(AvroSchemaClass.class);
DataStream<Row> rowInputStream = avroInputStream.map(new MapFunction<Orders_value, Row>() {
                @Override
                public Row map(AvroSchemaClass orders_value) throws Exception {
                    return avroToRow.deserialize(orders_value.toByteBuffer().array());
                }
            });

// Example transformation
DataStream<Row> rowOutputStream = rowInputStream.filter(row -> country.equals(row.getField(7).toString()));
       
CassandraSink streamSink = CassandraConnection.getSink(rowOutputStream,
                    cassandraURL,
                    cassandraPort,
                    cassandraCluster,
                    cassandraUser,
                    cassandraPass,
                    insertQuery);
streamSink.name("Write something to Cassandra");

environment.execute();
```

But when I run the job in flink, the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No support for the type of the given DataStream: GenericType<org.apache.flink.types.Row>
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.CassandraSink.addSink(CassandraSink.java:255)
        at servingLayer.CassandraConnection.getSink(CassandraConnection.java:24)
        at speedLayer.KafkaToCassandra.main(KafkaToCassandra.java:84)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Would a specific change of datastream type be the solution? and if yes, how to implement it?
Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: What's the idea to convert your Avro type to the Row type? I think you would be better off without this step.

Comment: @Arvid I'm using Row type in other jobs, so I hoped, that I can write universal code for transformations that uses only Row type. Is there maybe a better way to transform Avro to Row, so it will work with CassandraSink?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `CassandraSink` should support `Row` out of the box. The issue is that the `RowTypeInfo` of `rowOutputStream` is somehow lost and it uses the fallback `GenericType` (which is inefficiently serialized Kryo).

`AvroRowDeserializationSchema` is returning the type info correctly, but DataStream API is not picking that up automatically.

So if everything holds than a fix would be to explicitly set the return type of `rowIn/OutputStream` as follows

```
DataStream<Row> rowInputStream = avroInputStream.map(new MapFunction<Orders_value, Row>() {
            @Override
            public Row map(AvroSchemaClass orders_value) throws Exception {
                return avroToRow.deserialize(orders_value.toByteBuffer().array());
            }
        }).returns(avroToRow.getProducedType());
...
DataStream<Row> rowOutputStream = rowInputStream.filter(row -> country.equals(row.getField(7).toString()))
  .returns(avroToRow.getProducedType())
```

In general, it would be easier if you stick with one API. In this case, I'd recommend to fully go Table API.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `rowInputStream` has already the wrong `GenericType` type. So the source of the problem is probably not the `filter`, but the `AvroRowDeserializationSchema` or the avroSchemaClass `Orders_value`.  I changed the avroSchemaClass to an avroSchemaString, but the error stays.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation, I updated my answer such that it will hopefully work now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your update. `DataStream.returns()` doesn't exist, but I found a work-around for setting return type: `Transformation rowInputStreamTransformation = rowInputStream.getTransformation(); rowInputStreamTransformation.setOutputType(avroToRow.getProducedType());`
Unfortunately, I cannot confirm, it's working because Cassandra is not getting any values, but there aren't any errors in flink log. Do you have any advice for this problem?

Comment: I'm updating the solution again.

Comment: thanks for the update. Long story short: I probably need to ask another question, how to convert ConfluentAvroSchema to Row:
I got the following `java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.` FYI: I use Confluent Schema Registry. So I probably need to use a specific `ConfluentAvroRowDeserializationSchema`. I found this repo https://github.com/ztore/flink-registry-avro-row-schema. But its functions need a `flink.formats.avro.SchemaCoder.SchemaCoderProvider` as parameter. As I'm a java beginner I don't know how to implement this interface as needed as by the function.